# How to append a string when writing to a file in Unix

Tags: unix

I need to append some values when I try to write to a file.

I have a file named `all-ing-domains-uniq.txt`

So I am writing some values like below and this will create another file named `all-ssl-expiry-dates-of-domains.txt` with the following command.

```
for i in `cat all-ing-domains-uniq.txt`; do  curl -kv https://$i 2>&1 | grep -i "expire date:"  ; done >> all-ssl-expiry-dates-of-domains.txt
```

So this will write some values to the `all-ssl-expiry-dates-of-domains.txt` as below.

```
test1
test2
test3
test3
```

but I want to add the value of `i` as well, so it will look like this

```
start - test1
start2 - test2
start3 - test3
```

here the value of `i` is the `start`, `start2` and so on.

How can I do this?

Comment: `all-ing-domains-uniq.txt, currently, it is empty.` - and you're reading from it `cat all-ing-domains-uniq.txt`?

Comment: no it is not empty. It has values.

Comment: But you said it's empty.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk sorry it is not empty I updated the question